# $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor - \left\{ x \right\}:$ Increasing, Decreasing, Even , Odd, And/Or Invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, inverse-function, monotone-functions, parity

Define $\{x\} = x-\lfloor x \rfloor$. That is to say, $\{x\}$ is the "fractional part" of $x$. If you were to expand the number $x$ as a decimal, $\{x\}$ is the stuff after the decimal point. For example $\left\{\frac{3}{2}\right\} = 0.5$ and $\{\pi\} = 0.14159\dots$

Now, using the above definition, determine if the function below is increasing, decreasing, even, odd, and/or invertible on its natural domain:

$$f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor - \left\{ x \right\}$$

I think that it is invertible only, but I can't seem to find the inverse.  Am I correct saying that it is only invertible?  Is it also increasing, decreasing, even, and/or odd?

Comment: You are indeed correct that $f$ is injective. It is also surjective, and hence invertible. But proving these facts, and finding an inverse, will take a bit of work. You should try graphing this function first - on a small region, say $[0, 3]$. This will also help with the other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!  What about other properties?  Is the funtion also increasing, decreasing, even, and/or odd?

Comment: Have you tried graphing it? I think that will make the situation much clearer . . .

Comment: Once you graph it, you should start to have an idea about the answers to those.

Comment: I find it easier to visualise it as $f(x) = -x + 2 \lfloor x \rfloor$

Comment: I graphed it and it looks like this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/grapher/exports/rax2cuayg8.png

Comment: I think it is not increasing, not decreasing, not even, and not odd.  Am I correct?

Comment: @Regina Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Thanks!

Comment: To find the inverse, I suggest you take your graph, reflect it across the line $x = y$.  (I like to do the the primitive way.  sketch the graph in pencil.  Fold along the 45 degree line that is $x = y$, and rub with my fingernail to transfer some of the drawing, and darken it in).. look at this sketch of the inverse.  Guess at what function might fit.  And then show that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$

Comment: @DougM That's the method I use as well, but in this case it might lead to a wrong answer. For example, it made me think for a second that $f(x) + 2$ could be the inverse function, when it's not.

Comment: @rubik The inverse is $-f(-x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We verify that 
$$g(x)=-f(-x)=\{-x\}-\lfloor -x \rfloor$$
 is the inverse of $f$.
In fact if $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ then
$$f(g(x))=\lfloor \{-x\}-\lfloor -x \rfloor \rfloor
-\{\{-x\}-\lfloor -x \rfloor\}=\lfloor 0+x \rfloor
-\{0+x\}=x.$$
If $x\not\in \mathbb{Z}$ then
$$\lfloor -x \rfloor=-1-\lfloor x \rfloor\quad\mbox{and}\quad\{-x\}=1-\{x\}$$
and
$$f(g(x))=\lfloor \{-x\}-\lfloor -x \rfloor \rfloor
-\{\{-x\}-\lfloor -x \rfloor\}\\
=\lfloor 1-\{x\}-(-1-\lfloor x \rfloor) \rfloor
-\{1-\{x\}-(-1-\lfloor x \rfloor)\}\\
=\lfloor 2-\{x\}+\lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor
-\{2-\{x\}+\lfloor x \rfloor\}\\
=1+\lfloor x \rfloor-(1-\{x\})=\lfloor x \rfloor+\{x\}=x.$$

Answer (score 2):

$f(-1/2)=-3/2$ and   $f(1/2)=-1/2$ so $f$ is neither even nor odd.

$f(-1/2)=-3/2$ and $f(0)=0$ and $f(1/2)=-1/2$ so $f$ is neither increasing nor decreasing.

$f$ maps $[0,1)$ bijectively onto $(-1,0]$ because $f(x)=-x$ for $x\in [0,1).$

$f(x+1)=2+f(x)$ so if $x-y=n\in \mathbb Z$ then $f(x)=2n+f(y).$ So for $n\in \mathbb Z,$ the function $f$ maps $[n,n+1)$ bijectively onto $(2n-1,2n].$ So $f$ is 1-to-1.

And $\cup_{n\in \mathbb Z}(2n-1,2n]=\mathbb R.$ So $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a surjection. A 1-to-1 surjection is a bijection, and is invertible.

Remarks: In case it is unclear that $f$ is 1-to-1, note that (1) when $n\in \mathbb Z$ and $x,y\in [n,n+1)$ then $f(x)\ne f(y)$ because $f$ is 1-to-1 on $[n,n+1)$. And (2) when $m,n$ are unequal integers and $x\in [m,m+1)$ and $y\in [n,n+1)$ then $f(x)\in (2m-1,2m]$ while $f(y)\in (2m-1,2m],$ and $(2m-1,2m]\cap (2n-1,2n]$ is empty, so $f(x)\ne f(y).$

It may be helpful to sketch the graph of $f.$